# Sort nested list of numbers in increasing order of values and size

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say I have 5 lists of numbers:

```
[
    (1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18),
    (3, 7, 19, 8),
    (1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18, 7),
    (5, 11, 16, 18, 21),
    (3, 7, 7, 8)
]
```

I would like to sort these lists in the following way:

"look" at the first number in each list. The place of the list after the sort will be determined by how small the number is - the smaller it is, the higher it will be.

For every list that had the same first number, you settle the score by doing the same with the second number:

```
(1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18),    
(1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18, 7)
```

and

```
(3, 7, 19, 8),    
(3, 7, 7, 8)
```

And if you still need to settle the score, you do it to the third, fourth, fifth, etc, until the score is settled.

If there is a list that is the same as another list, but with more numbers in the end of it:

```
(5, 7, 10, 11),
(5, 7, 10)
```

The shorter list will be first.

So in the end, the example I gave should look like this:

```
[
    (1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18),
    (1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18, 7),
    (3, 7, 7, 8),
    (3, 7, 19, 8),
    (5, 11, 16, 18, 21)
]
```

I can't figure out how to program this. Any answers to this?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you written any code so far? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: This is called lexicographic ordering, and it's how lists sort by default.

Comment: How do you think you would solve this problem? It sounds a lot like you're asking SO to do your homework for you...

Comment: I don't really know where to start. I'm trying to imagine some ways to do this, but they seem very complicated and way out of my league. I'm a relatively new programmer.

Comment: That is, for two lists `a` and `b`, `a < b` if `a[0] < b[0]` or `a[0] == b[0]` and `a[1:] < b[1:]`. As a base case, `[]` is less than any non-empty list and `[] < []` is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to write any code for it at all; `list.sort()` and `sorted()` do this already.

Comment: It seemed to work at first, but then I threw at it something and it gave me this: imgur.com/a/LF5krf5 it starts off in order, first there is something that starts with a 1, then another one that starts with 1, then 13, then 15, but then it goes back to 2, then 4, then 5. why?

Comment: @Remeraze i cannot reproduce this behaviour, please post the code you tried

Comment: here are the lists: paste.ubuntu.com/p/HmmT9VvyDs (ignore the '1' at the start, I don't know why it's there).


I did:


`b = [TEXT IN LINK]`,


`a = sorted(b)`,

`print(a)`,

Comment: @Remeraze in the pastebin code the sub lists are quoted, you have to unquote them !

Comment: @Remeraze please accept my answer or the answer of 
MoinuddinQuadri

Answer (score 4):

That's the default sorting order (known as *lexicographic* sort) of `list.sort()` and `sorted()` functions. `list.sort()` performs the sorting *in-place* i.e. within same list, whereas `sorted()` returns a new list.

Example of **`list.sort()`**:

```
>>> my_list = [(1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18), (3, 7, 19, 8), (1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18, 7), (5, 11, 16, 18, 21), (3, 7, 7, 8)]
>>> my_list.sort()
>>> my_list
[(1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18), (1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18, 7), (3, 7, 7, 8), (3, 7, 19, 8), (5, 11, 16, 18, 21)]
```

Example of **`sorted()`**:

```
>>> my_list = [(1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18), (3, 7, 19, 8), (1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18, 7), (5, 11, 16, 18, 21), (3, 7, 7, 8)]
>>> sorted(my_list)
[(1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18), (1, 20, 5, 8, 14, 18, 7), (3, 7, 7, 8), (3, 7, 19, 8), (5, 11, 16, 18, 21)]
```

Comment: It seemed to work at first, but then I threw at it something and it gave me this:
https://imgur.com/a/LF5krf5

it starts off in order, first there is something that starts with a 1, then another one that starts with 1, then 13, then 15, but then it goes back to 2, then 4, then 5. why?

Comment: Since there were lists inside of the list, the `.sort()` function didn't work. Make sure you mention that we have to use the `for loop`.

Comment: how will the `for` loop help in this case?

Comment: I am not sure what the list in your image mean. But definitely you must be doing something different than what you asked here. Above solution will work for all the lists in the format you mentioned in the question, **always!** You can create a separate question with your code and example if you seek help

Comment: @Remeraze if this answer helped you, you can [upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) by clicking up arrow on the left. It will help me with 10 reputation gain. You can also mark the answer as accepted (best answer among all) by clicking tick icon on the left of the answer